# Prove a group G is abelian if it satisfies x^2 = x for every x in G

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

I originally solved this problem by simply noting that x^2 = x implies x=e, so the only element in the group is the identity...but this is wrong. I am now stuck on this idea though and I have tried experimentation with manipulation of elements and gotten nowhere. I know I am probably overthinking it but I just can't see how to prove this group is abelian

Comment: why is it wrong? wouldn't the question be $x^2=e$ for all $x$?

Comment: When proving abelian-ness, you usually need two elements and to show that $ab=ba$, right?

Comment: There is another question on the assignment that has the x^2=e requirement so this one is different. And yes, you do need to show ab=ba, I just don't know how to get there

Comment: Your reasoning correctly deduces that $G$ must be the trivial group, which is certainly abelian since its only element commutes with itself.

Comment: $x^2=x$ for all $x$ does imply $G=\{e\}$. I think maybe you misread the problem and your problem is actually: Prove that $G$ is abelian if it satisfies $x^2=e$ for all $x\in G$.

Comment: @abiessu: Been there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x,y \in G, \space (xy)^2=xy \Rightarrow xyxy=x^2y^2 \Rightarrow x^{-1}xyxyy^{-1}=x^{-1}x^2y^2y^{-1} \Rightarrow yx=xy$

So the group is abelian.

Comment: Perhaps explain the down votes so you can be constructive?

Comment: As far as I can see that seems correct, I don't understand the down votes either.

Comment: I don't understand neither ;).

Comment: It is correct. But too much proof for G={e}. Nevertheless I don't understand the downvotes.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, if $G$ is a group where every element verify $x^2=x$, then it's the trivial group $\{e\}$.

Indeed, $x^2 =x \Rightarrow x^2x^{-1} = xx^{-1} \Rightarrow x=e$

Comment: I don't argue that the logic isn't  correct, but when I got my assignment back I did not receive full marks so clearly I need to prove more than I did

Comment: @Francesca do you have a picture of your work? Maybe you didn't get the grade you deserved.

Comment: @carryonsmiling I got 2/3, and it says "G could be an infinite Matrix group" as the comment...not really sure what that means to be honest

Comment: I'm pretty sure you copied the question wrong then. Are you sure it isn't $x^2=e$ for all $x$ ?

Comment: @Francesca If the question is really “Prove a group $G$ is abelian if it satisfies $x^2=x$ for every $x\in G$”, then your mark was inaccurate, because the only group with this property is finite, actually it consists just of the identity. You can have no doubt about this.